# Script to auto-layout a 6-column printed newspaper

Tags: desktop-publishing

I'm looking for a software or script to auto-layout a 6-column printed newspaper with given news.

I will provide the "category" (page n.) for every news and some photos to choose between (to fit white space left by text).

I will provide some ads to fit white space.

Comment: I'm sure you can accomplish this with LaTeX and some programming. Try asking for advice at tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Apart from that, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) What OS or scripting language? Any price limit (just in case)? Apart from columns, what must it support (e.g. text-flow around images)? What's the input format of your "given news"? What's the source (local, web content, …) and the "ads to fit white space"?